# How to route url - Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, url-routing

I'm creating a new webpage were my users can have profile pages, and I can't seem to find the way to make a url like this:

`webpage.com/profile/username`

To go to my `profile_controller` action `index` and use the variable that comes on /username.

But I can't seem to find the way.

profile_controller.rb

```
class ProfileController < ApplicationController
  def index
    profile_info = Profile.find(params[:username])
  end
end
```

And I've tried to work it around with the routes.rb but couldn't make it...

Comment: Post the output of `rake routes`.  That will give us all the configured routes and helper functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This route in your routes.rb should map get requests on /profiles/username to the index action of your profiles controller and pass the username value in params[:username]

```
get '/profiles/:username' => 'profiles#index'
```